# change DNS records A for a lot of domains

Tags: domain-name-system

I’m managing a lot of domains on different provider for my clients.

These domains are pointing to the same server.

If I would change this server I should change the IP address on DNS record for each domains.

Is there a best solutions?

Sorry for the newbie question and sorry my english :)

Thanks

Comment: It depends who hosts your DNS, but you'll probably need to change them individually. You've given us virtually no information about your DNS so we can't help.

Comment: I'm sorry, I phrased the question wrong.
My real question was if there is a way to point all my domains to another domain.
So if I would change my server i'll change only one record.
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This is where CNAMEs come in handy. Whenever I've needed to do this in the past, I've created a single A record, and used CNAMEs to manage the actual sites. For example:

```
www-vip IN A 1.1.1.1
site1 IN CNAME www-vip
site2 IN CNAME www-vip
```

Then, you change the www-vip A record, and all CNAMEs are redirected without change.

You can refactor into this model live, and then when you're ready to cut over, it will be a single change.

Comment: Hi Cerberus, thanks for your reply.
mmm… Maybe I don’t understand, I have tried in this way:
main domain = pippo.com

pippo.com IN A 1.1.1.1
www.pippo.com IN A 1.1.1.1

others domain:
www.site1.com IN CNAME pippo.com
www.site2.com IN CNAME pippo.com

And this works!!!

but unfortunately without “www” doesn’t work, for example:
site1.com IN CNAME pippo.com

I can’t save this record I display an error.

Is it normal?

Thanks

Comment: The other record you cannot save would actually be part of a different zone. Within that domain's zone, you should be able to save the record.

Comment: Hi Cerberus, I change the domain’s zone but i’m not able to save the new record.

i find this answer: “You can’t do this for example.com because example.com will also have NS records to make it work which breaks the rule that no other data should be present” source: http://superuser.com/questions/264913/cant-set-example-com-as-a-cname-record. 
I would like to find a good solution to this problem.